# How to convert Unicode char to "Unicode HEX Position" in Arduino or C

Tags: c, unicode, arduino

How to convert Unicode char to "Unicode HEX Position" in Arduino or C

i will share a picture here :

[image]

for example in JavaScript you can do that with `charCodeAt();` !
this function will return exactly the char-code and then you can convert it to hex!

for example in JavaScript i can do that like this to return exact table value

```js
    var inpString = 'س';
    var myChar=0;
    var output = 0;
    myChar = inpString.charCodeAt(0);
    output = (ToHex((myChar&0xff00)>>8 )) + (ToHex( myChar&0xff ));
    
    function ToHex(i)
    {
        var sHex = "0123456789ABCDEF";
        var Out = "";
        Out = sHex.charAt(i&0xf);
        i>>=4;
        Out = sHex.charAt(i&0xf) + Out;
        return Out;
    }
    alert(output);
```

So how can i do that in Arduino or C ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? How is your string stored? And how is the chart related to the issue?

Comment: @Gerhardh anything that you ever think, but no success! there is a lots of way to do that but not for unicode char

Comment: JavaScript works internally with UCS-2 or UTF-16 characters, C (for practical uses) with 8 bit characters. So one is "Unicode" native, the second no. So we should know which encoding do you need (e.g. what your Arduino library expect), and from there we can answer

Comment: @Gerhardh charCodeAt is not return charAt ! its returns "char Code" At position, in C [0] will return char not char code , (int)inpString[0] in C is not return unicode position

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi thank you for your attention, i just need to convert unicode char like this -> 'س' to correct Unicode HEX Position that i shared in the picture above
i think its UTF-16 because its 2 byte

Comment: this has an accepted answer here ... https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/76881/how-to-convert-unicode-char-to-unicode-hex-position-in-arduino

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is a big problem for who are looking to send multipart SMS via GSM modem like sim800 with Arduino or AVR

sure there is some other way to send unicode SMS but the problem happening when you are trying to send multi part SMS, so your only option is using PDU mode then you will get stuck between encoding 7bit ascii and 16bit unicode and the only way is to find a way to convert char to "Unicode HEX Position" like picture that i shared in my first post,
however finally "Edgar Bonet" Posts the answer in stackexchange and i will share the link here for who have same problem

https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/76886/67600

Special Thanks to "Edgar Bonet"

Comment: that answer will work only if the message is a string literal in the source code. it will not work if the message is received for example from Serial Monitor

Comment: @juraj thank you for your attention, correct but my problem was not serial communication i just searching to finding a way to do that inside the source code

Answer (score 0):

found an answer if you need to do the conversion on the fly (and not just with a string in the source code).

Solution is here:

http://bjoern.hoehrmann.de/utf-8/decoder/dfa/

Working example, table stored in PROGMEM:

```
#define UTF8_ACCEPT 0
#define UTF8_REJECT 1

static const uint8_t utf8d_PROGMEM[] PROGMEM = {
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, // 00..1f
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, // 20..3f
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, // 40..5f
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, // 60..7f
  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, // 80..9f
  7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, // a0..bf
  8, 8, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, // c0..df
  0xa, 0x3, 0x3, 0x3, 0x3, 0x3, 0x3, 0x3, 0x3, 0x3, 0x3, 0x3, 0x3, 0x4, 0x3, 0x3, // e0..ef
  0xb, 0x6, 0x6, 0x6, 0x5, 0x8, 0x8, 0x8, 0x8, 0x8, 0x8, 0x8, 0x8, 0x8, 0x8, 0x8, // f0..ff
  0x0, 0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x5, 0x8, 0x7, 0x1, 0x1, 0x1, 0x4, 0x6, 0x1, 0x1, 0x1, 0x1, // s0..s0
  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, // s1..s2
  1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, // s3..s4
  1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, // s5..s6
  1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, // s7..s8
};

uint32_t decode(uint32_t* state, uint32_t* codep, uint32_t byte) {
  uint8_t utf8d;
  memcpy_P(&utf8d, &utf8d_PROGMEM[byte], sizeof utf8d);
  uint32_t type = utf8d;
  *codep = (*state != UTF8_ACCEPT) ?
           (byte & 0x3fu) | (*codep << 6) :
           (0xff >> type) & (byte);
  memcpy_P(&utf8d, &utf8d_PROGMEM[256 + *state * 16 + type], sizeof utf8d);
  *state = utf8d;
  return *state;
}

const char mystring[] = "Kulaťoučký míč";

void printCodePoints(uint8_t* s) {
  uint32_t codepoint;
  uint32_t state = 0;
  for (; *s; ++s) {
    if (decode(&state, &codepoint, *s))
      continue;
    if (codepoint <= 0xFFFF) {
      if (codepoint < 0x1000)
        Serial.print(F("0"));
      if (codepoint < 0x0100)
        Serial.print(F("0"));
      if (codepoint < 0x0010)
        Serial.print(F("0"));
      Serial.print(codepoint, HEX);
      continue;
    }
    // Encode code points above U+FFFF as surrogate pair.
    //    Serial.println((0xD7C0 + (codepoint >> 10)), HEX);
    //    Serial.println((0xDC00 + (codepoint & 0x3FF)), HEX);
  }
  Serial.println();
  if (state != UTF8_ACCEPT)
    Serial.println("The string is not well-formed\n");
}

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);

  printCodePoints((uint8_t*)mystring);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```